# Core Data concurrency with app extensions

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, osx-yosemite

I'm developing an app extension that needs to share data with the containing app. I created an app group and moved the core data store of the main app to that folder.  From the extension I can create the managed object context and save data to the store and I can also access it from the containing app.  Now I have two independent applications accessing the same core data store.  This sounds like a recipe for disaster to me. Is what I have set up sufficient for sending data from the extension to the containing app or should I look for another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation you'll have two entirely independent Core Data stacks accessing the same persistent store file.

Assuming that you're using SQLite, you're fine, at least as far as data integrity. Core Data uses SQLite transactions to save changes and SQLite is fine with multiple processes using the same file. Neither process will corrupt data for the other or mess up the file.

You *will* have to deal with keeping data current in the app. For example if someone uses the share extension to create new data while the app is running. You won't get anything like `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` in this case. You'll need to find your own way to ensure you get any new updates.

In many cases you can make this almost trivial-- listen for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`, which will be posted any time your app comes to the foreground. When you get it, check the persistent store for new data and load it.

If you want to get a little more elegant, you could use something like [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) for a sort-of file based IPC between the app and the extension. Then the extension can explicitly inform the app that there's new data, and the app can respond.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting answer from Tom Harrington. However I need to mention about `MMWormhole`. I've found that `MMWormhole` uses `NSFileCoordinator` and apple tells that:

> Using file coordination in an app extension to access a container
>   shared with its containing app may result in a deadlock in iOS
>   versions 8.1.x and earlier.

What Apple suggests for safe save operations you can read here:

> You can use `CFPreferences`, atomic safe save operations on flat
>   files, or `SQLite` or `Core Data` to share data in a group container
>   between multiple processes even if one is suspended mid transaction.

[Here is the link to the Apple Technical Note TN2408](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2408/_index.html).